# Dynamically show drill down BIRT report

Tags: birt, drilldown

Hi I need to add drill down to birt report based on the value in text field that value get from the database.So as example if value greater than 100 we need to show drill down if not no need to show drill down.Is there anyway to handle dynamic drill down in birt report.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Video](http://demo.actuate.com/demos/drill/drill.html) demonstrates how to create a drill down. Its basically a hyperlink added to a Data Element that opens another Report and transfers values from its context (like the value of the selected data cell) to the input parameters of the report to be opened.

To disable the drill down Hyperlink on the cells with a value below 100 you select the cell and then select the `Script` Tab. Select `OnCreate` from the dropdown and enter the following code to remove the Hyperlink on condition:

```
if( this.getValue() < 100 ){
    this.action = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is help me.

Answer (score 0):

This simple example  helps the way i need to resolve problem.

```
if(a > 100){
var myaction =this.createAction();
importPackage(Packages.java.util);
 var hm = new HashMap();
 hm.put("parameter1","value");
 hm.put("parameter2","value2"); 
 this.action = myaction;
 var dt =this.action.createDrillThrough();
 dt.setReportName("drill_down_design2.rptdesign");
 dt.setTargetWindow("_blank");
 dt.setTargetFileType("report-design");
 dt.setParameterBindings(hm);
 myaction.setDrillThrough(dt);

}
```